# mbsync not downloading new mails?

Tags: email, synchronization

My `.mbsyncrc` file includes the lines

```
MaxMessages 1000
ExpireUnread yes
```

However, when attempting to download my gmails, it doesn't seem to sync the newest ones.  For example, I've just done an `mbsync`, and my mutt inbox is missing about 30 emails which should have come in today.  In fact there are no emails in my mutt inbox dated today (July 11).  I really don;t want my local slave files to grow larger and larger, and in fact keeping only the most recent 1000 emails is fine.

How can I sync only the 1000 most recent emails locally, while keeping the rest on the gmail server?